# How can I make annotation for djvu file when using Okular?

Tags: okular, djvu

My OS is `[03/13/2020,14:35:06@~]$ uname -a
Linux debian 4.19.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.98-1 (2020-01-26) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

That is, Debian 10 (Buster). When in Debian 9, I can make annotation in djvu file with Okular. But now I cannot. Below is a typical process of trial.

Start Okular.  Open with Okular, a djvu file named 1.djvu. Now use Hilighter[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxs3f.png) to make some annotation. Then close the file 1.djvu. Thus, a popup reads: Do you want to save your changes to "1.djvu" or discard them? (see screenshot[image])
I choose "Save". Then another popup says:Warning-Okular  You are about to save changes, but the current file format does not support saving the following elements. Please use the Okular document archive format to preserve them. So, I click "Use annotations", and then choose "Save as Okular document archive...". (See screenshot[image])
Now also a popup reads "After saving, the current document format requires the file to be reloaded. Your undo/redo history will be lost. Do you want to continue?"  I choose "Yes". (See screenshot[image])  And the file 1.djvu is saved as 2.djvu. Now I open 2.djvu by Okular. But a popup reads "Could not open file:///.../2.djvu". See this[image]. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Rename the file so that the file extension is `.okular` instead of `.djvu`. This worked for me.

Comment: Wow! This solution is so messed up! Thanks! I had this problem too.

Comment: Dammit, after reopening the .okular document, adding some more annotations, and trying to save them again, it said that the changes cannot be saved because the file has been modified by another program (the one in which I was viewing it, no doubt :q ), even when I tried to "Save As…" with a different name. And after closing the file and opening again, all my changes are lost! ;o  So neither can I update the annotations nor save a new file with more annotations. Any solutions for that? :q  This is getting really ridiculous and annoying. WHO MADE THAT?! ;o